# Parsing incorrect html with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, linq, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to parse the following HTML:

```
<li>
    <b style="font-size: 11px;">News:</b>
    <ul>
        <li><a style="font-size: 11px;" title="Program 1">program1</a></li>
        <li><a style="font-size: 11px;" title="Program 2">program2</a></li>
        <li><a style="font-size: 11px;" title="Program 3">program3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <b style="font-size: 11px;">Cartoons:</b>
    <ul>
        <li><a style="font-size: 11px;" title="Program 4">program4</a></li>
        <li><a style="font-size: 11px;" title="Program 5">program5</a></li>
        <li><a style="font-size: 11px;" title="Program 6">program6</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <b style="font-size: 11px;">Music:</b>
    <ul>
        <li><a style="font-size: 11px;" title="Program 7">program7</a></li>
        <li><a style="font-size: 11px;" title="Program 8">program8</a></li>
        <li><a style="font-size: 11px;" title="Program 9">program9</a></li>                     
    </ul>
</li>
```

What I want to get is the type of program ( inner text) and name of the programs ( inner text).

The results I want to put them in the following object:

```
public class Programs
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

This is my current code:

```
var content = from li in document.DocumentNode.Descendants("li")
                          from b in li.Descendants("b")
                          from a in li.Descendants("a")
                          where a.Attributes["title"] != null && a.Attributes["title"].Value.StartsWith("Program")
                          select new Channel
                          {
                              Name = a.InnerText,
                              Category = b.InnerText
                          };

            foreach (Programs c in content)
            {
                string s = c.Name;
                string ss = c.Category;
            }
```

But for every program I get only the "News" category.
How should I do to get the correct categories ? (News - program1, program2, program3, Cartoons - program4, program5, program6... ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, strange. Just downloaded latest `HtmlAgilityPack` and tried your example and it give me correct results:

```
News:: program1
News:: program2
News:: program3
Cartoons:: program4
Cartoons:: program5
Cartoons:: program6
Music:: program7
Music:: program8
Music:: program9
```

My test code is:

```
 var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
 htmlDoc.Load("test.txt");
 var items = from li in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("li")
             from b in li.Descendants("b")
             from a in li.Descendants("a")
             where a.Attributes["title"] != null && 
             a.Attributes["title"].Value.StartsWith("Program")
             select new
             {
               Name = a.InnerText,
               Category = b.InnerText
             };

 foreach (var item in items)
 {
   Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Category, item.Name);
 }
 Console.ReadKey();
```

I guess you missed something simple in your code. Btw 'test.txt' file contains above html.

Comment: Hmm, investigating a little I see that I get all programs with the News category and then all programs with the Cartons category, and then again all programs with the Music category...strange